# Export Umbraco Media Tree Structure

Tags: umbraco, umbraco4

Is there a way to export the tree structure from Umbraco media section?

I have managed to do the same for "Content" section building a package on developer tab but I cannot do the same for "Media".

I'm using Umbraco 4.

[image]

Comment: Are you just wanting to export the node names of the media library? Say for example in a UL?

Comment: Actually I wanted the entire structure with related attributes in an exchangeable file like xml or csv.